# jasig cas incorrect authentication

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, cas, jasig

I have a jasig CAS server implemented at my community college. We successfully use this to log into Gmail and quite a few other applications. When writing an application in VS2012 (C#) I decided to hook into that so I could minimize the login hassles. It worked beautifully in testing, but we tested the code with only one user.
Now that it is live, it seems that one user is receiving the login validation of another user who logs onto a different computer after the first user logs in. Would anyone have an idea how this may happen? Was this a bug that may be solved by upgrading our CAS version?

Comment: I believe that I have found a workaround. I have created a local cookie and authenticated with CAS only the first time. This seems to work well, but there should be a better way to get it done.

Comment: Are you using the .NET client? What version of CAS are you using? Service tickets should be unique. It is hard to believe two users can get the same ticket. You should check the CAS audit log and pay close attention to the username, service ticket, and ip.